# What are the differences between these 2 examples

Tags: past-tense

then he remembered what had happened at the weekend. On Saturday afternoon his new car **had disappeared** from the road in front of his house. Sam called the police but ten minutes later his brother drove up.

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/106820893/Mix-Tense-in-Context

South London called Broadway Sound. Early on the morning of August 12th 1982 the band, comprising of Colin Swan, Geno Buckmaster, Brian Grover and their trusty roadie ‘Robbo’ assembled at the tiny studio to begin recording as many of their songs as they could get down on tape for the tiny budget they had scraped together. As most of the songs **were already well rehearsed** thanks to the band’s busy live schedule, the recording of the first nine songs on this disc were finished by mid afternoon without any problems.

I don't see any differences in these two examples. My question is why the second one is past simple .I have tried to compare them . Here is the result of my comparison

Both are about events that took place before, both are easy to understand  that they took place before (even for the first one without using past perfect ), both are  causes  (the car had been stolen so he called the police the song had been already well rehearsed so the disc was finished early )and both seems to be completed   **so what and where  is the difference**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the answer to your previous question about this passage was deleted. It explains that *rehearsed* here functions as an adjective. The songs were 'rehearsed' in the sense of being well-known to the band through having often been performed in concert.

Sam's car *had disappeared,* but we could also say that it *was missing.*

Comment: The author could equally well have said _the songs had already been well rehearsed._ It was just their stylistic choice.

Comment: You were told in response to an earlier question that there is nothing wrong with _had been rehearsed_!

Comment: so it is only a stylistic choice  but if you were the author of  this text what would you write past perfect or past simple and why

Comment: I would probably say _most of the songs didn't need much rehearsal_!

Comment: but I asked between past simple and past perfect without changing the rest of the sentence . As" well rehearsed" is employed as an adjective it may be  better to use past simple as it is a state